# std::ranges::take_while_view cannot pipe

Tags: c++, std-ranges

```
auto int_v10 = std::vector{8,7,3};
//fail    auto rng2 = int_v10 | std::ranges::take_while_view([](int x) {return x> 5;} ) | std::ranges::views::common;
auto rng2 = int_v10 | std::ranges::views::take_while([](int x) {return x> 5;} ) | std::ranges::views::common;
auto result4 = std::accumulate(rng2.begin(), rng2.end(),0);

std::cout<<"Result4: "<<result4<<'\n';
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_while_view
Why `std::ranges::take_while_view` result cannot pipe to next code block.
and `std::ranges::views::take_while` can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`take_while_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_while_view) has only [two constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_while_view/take_while_view):

```
take_while_view() = default;
constexpr take_while_view(V base, Pred pred);
```

The second constructor needs to accept *two* parameters, one is base and the other is pred, so you need to struct it like this:

```
auto rng2 = std::ranges::take_while_view(int_v10, [](int x) {return x > 5;}) 
          | std::ranges::views::common;
```